# TortoiseSVN switching branch - some files stay on previous branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When using TortoiseSVN on Windows to switch branch, occasionally some files and/or folders will remain on the previous branch.  There seems to be no consistent pattern to this.  It doesn't happen every time, and it doesn't happen to the same files.  So usually you only find out about it when there's a problem due to the old file no longer working in conjuction with the new files.

So I'd like either of two things:

1. A way to consistently switch branch that prevents this happening again
2. If that's not possible, some way of listing the entire contents of a directory along with which branch each file and folder is in.

Comment: Are you switching while you have uncommited changes in the working copy?

Comment: Possibly, although it's not these uncommitted files that end up out of sync.  It seems to be random files, not necessarily ones you've been working on recently.  Usually I just end up repeating the switch, or checking out the problematic files/folders again

Answer (score 1):

That's expected behavior according to [Tortoise's docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html):

> Switch works just like Update in that
>   it never discards your local changes.
>   Any changes you have made to your
>   working copy which have not yet been
>   committed will be merged when you do
>   the Switch. If you do not want this to
>   happen then you must either commit the
>   changes before switching, or revert
>   your working copy to an
>   already-committed revision (typically
>   HEAD).

Comment: No, it's NOT files that I've changed locally that end up out of sync.  It seems to be any random file.  And it's not that the files remain different locally from in the repository, they're actually in the wrong branch.  e.g. I switch the entire directory from Branch 1 to Branch 2.  Then, just occasionally, some files will still be in Branch 1.

Comment: So you have files that exist in Branch 1 and Branch 2 but are different. And then when you switch from Branch 1 to Branch 2, the version of the file is Branch 1's copy and not overwritten with Branch 2's changes?

Comment: Basically that's what seems to be happening.

Comment: My understanding is that the new additional files in Branch 1 essentially become working copies in Branch 2 because Branch 2 has zero knowledge of them. Unless you remove files via svn delete a switch or update command will not delete them from your working copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a clean working copy (no changes), you shouldn't have this problem.

You could do a `revert` followed by a `switch`. You will lose any changes you have made to your working copy though.

Alternatively you could `commit` your changes then `switch`